# Functionality and excution of queueStream in SparkStreaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

What is the functionality of the `queueStream` function in Spark `StreamingContext`. According to my understanding it is a queue which queues the incoming `DStream`. If that is the case then how it is handled in the cluster with many node. Does each node will have this `queueStream` and the `DStream` is partitioned among all the nodes in the cluster? How does this `queueStream` work in cluster setup?

I have read below explanation in the [Spark Streaming documentation][https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#basic-sources), but I didn't understand it completely. Please help me to understand it.

> **Queue of RDDs as a Stream:** For testing a Spark Streaming application with test data, one can also create a DStream based on a queue of RDDs, using streamingContext.queueStream(queueOfRDDs). Each RDD pushed into the queue will be treated as a batch of data in the DStream, and processed like a stream.

```
val myQueueRDD= scala.collection.mutable.Queue[RDD[MyObject]]()
val myStream= ssc.queueStream(myQueueRDD)

for(count <- 1 to 100) {
        val randomData= generateData() //Generated random data
        val rdd= ssc.sparkContext.parallelize(randomData) //Creates the rdd of the random data.
        myQueueRDD+= rdd //Addes data to queue.
}

myStream.foreachRDD(rdd => rdd.mapPartitions(data => evaluate(data)))
```

How the above part of the code will get executed in the spark streaming context with respect to partitions on different nodes.

Answer (score 2):

`QueueInputDStream` is intended for testing. It uses standard `scala.collection.mutable.Queue` to store `RDDs` which imitate incoming batches.

> Does each node will have this queueStream and the DStream is partitioned among all the nodes in the cluster

No. There is only one copy of the queue and all data distribution is handled by `RDDs`. `compute` logic is very simple with `dequeue` (`oneAtATime` set to `true`) or `union` of the current queue (`oneAtATime` set to `false`) at each tick. This applies to `DStreams` in general -  each stream is just a sequence of RDDs, which provide data distribution mechanism.

While it still follows `InputDStream` API, conceptually it is just a local collection from which you take elements every `batchDuration`.

Comment: You are catching up with me ! ;-)

Comment: Yes. If there is only one queue then how the RDD distribution happen, this is the part i want clarity. If the queue is in only in the driver then partition and computation how it happens in parallel in all the nodes?

Comment: Can you please checkout the edit of the question which gives clarity on my doubt @user6910411